# Is it possible to create a 2-dimensional radio button set?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have three sets of data (`dataX`, `dataY`, `dataZ`) that should each be assigned a different value out of a possible three (`valueA`, `valueB`, `valueC`). Each piece of data must be assigned to one value and each value must be assigned one data.

I hoped to use a set of radio buttons to do this:

```
dataX: <label><input type="radio" name="dataX" value="valueA">valueA</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dataX" value="valueB">valueB</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dataX" value="valueC">valueC</label><br>

dataY: <label><input type="radio" name="dataY" value="valueA">valueA</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dataY" value="valueB">valueB</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dataY" value="valueC">valueC</label><br>

dataZ: <label><input type="radio" name="dataZ" value="valueA">valueA</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dataZ" value="valueB">valueB</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dataZ" value="valueC">valueC</label>
```

(http://jsbin.com/todoseyu/1/)

This ensures `dataX` (for example) can only be assigned to one value. However, it doesn't stop further data being assigned to the same value (`dataX`, `dataY` and `dataZ` could all be assigned to `valueA` for example).

Is there some way of making a 2-dimensional radio button set that will allow the required functionality? Or do I need to resort to javascript?

Comment: use a `class` and secondly show your code as well

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee ??? What do you mean 'use a class'? And there is no more relevant code to show...

Comment: did you tried anything to provide a check.
well sol is:
add class to each radio button and then in jquery check whether its checked it true then dont check else check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in HTML, because radio buttons work as simple sets (defined so that radio buttons with the same `name` attribute act as one functional set). There is no way to make the choice in one set depend on choices in other sets.

In JavaScript, you can handle this in several ways. For example, you can make a choice in the first set disable the same choice in other sets, setting the `disabled` attribute on them and graying out their labels.

You could also use something like a set of visible items (A, B, C) and boxes (X, Y, Z) to which they can be dragged and dropped. This might mean better usability, but the HTML5 Drag and Drop API is perhaps not yet sufficiently cross-browser.

Comment: Drag and drop is an excellent idea. I reckon combining the use of javascript with a drag and drop interface should be very intuitive